# Confirming my calculation of mean, standard deviation and median for a histogram

Tags: mean, histogram

[image: Histogram]

> Average travel time* for men = 27.2 minutes, women = 23.6 minutes

My calculations are the followings:

[image: My Calculations]

The problem is **my calculated mean is 28.4** but **chart says 27.2**

I calculate the mean with this formula: **(sum of products of midpoint and freq) / sum of freq**

Comment: What travel time did you use for 'worked at home'?

Comment: It might be that 'up to 5 minutes' includes up to 4m59s which makes 2m30s the midpoint, same for other intervals. That only gets the mean down to 28.04 though, your approximation assumes all data points in a bin are symmetric around its center, which likely doesn't hold here. Is there any reason you can't just use the reported mean?

Comment: @PBulls The reason is that I want to be able to calculate it myself. So maybe they calculated the mean with the actual data, right?

Comment: @Glen_b I didn't include it, as the chart itself also excludes it.

Comment: The first chart shows it as the last category

Comment: @Glen_b yes but at the very end it states it was excluded from the mean